# How can I make an object not drop a shadow in eevee but keep the shadows on itself?

Tags: materials, shadows

I dont want this shadow to be cast, but I want the shadows to be kept that are on the mesh of the projector object. So the method of disabling the shadows in the materials settings won't work. Im looking for a similar option to the shadows off option in the ray tracing settings of cycles, but for eevee.
[image]

Comment: I have no idea if there is a good way to do this... I would do the following: create a duplicate scene, delete everything except for the projector and the scene lights. In the original scene duplicate the materials of the projector with _Shadow Mode_ > _None_. Render both scenes, the second one with only the projector and lights with _Film_ > _Transparent_. Then use _Alpha Over_ in the _Compositor_ to put the projector with shadows over the scene without shadows. If there were objects obstructing the projector, they need to be in the duplicate scene as well set to _Holdout_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Don’t need separate scenes, just use layers. Otherwise, yeah: Use compositing for this one.

Comment: @TheLabCat Yeah sure, you're right. Something like that, I guess compositing is the only way in Eevee.

Comment: @TheLabCat ... of course it's dependent on the scene, but let's say I don't want to render the original layer with _Film_ > _Transparent_, is there a way in the _View Layers_ method to render one with background and the other transparent?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That is a good point. I have yet to find a solution to that. I am going to ask it as a question now.